# The mechanism of equating functions in python

Tags: python, decorator

I learned that we can equate one function with another in Python like this:

```
def func_1(x)
    print("func_1")
    print(x)

def func_2(x)
    print("func_2")
    print(x)

func_1 =func_2
```

So here what is happening is every call to func_1 executes func_2.

However, I read about decorators and the following is a simple code illustrating them:

```
def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(x):
        print("Before calling " + func.__name__)
        func(x)
        print("After calling " + func.__name__)
    return function_wrapper

def foo(x):
    print("Hi, foo has been called with " + str(x))

print("We call foo before decoration:")
foo("Hi")

print("We now decorate foo with f:")
foo = our_decorator(foo)

print("We call foo after decoration:")
foo(42)
```

Here as we can see in the following line:

```
foo = our_decorator(foo)
```

something like the previous function equation is taking place . I thought this is how decorators might be working, i.e., replacing call to the decoratee by call to decorator .

However, under this impression if I write up a code like the following:

```
def our_decorator():
    def function_wrapper(x):
        print("Before calling " )
        foo(x)
        print("After calling " )
    return function_wrapper

def foo(x):
    print("Hi, foo has been called with " + str(x))

print("We call foo before decoration:")
foo("Hi")

print("We now decorate foo with f:")
foo = our_decorator()

print("We call foo after decoration:")
foo(42)
```

The above results in infinite recursion printing infinite number of "Before calling ".

So, I could conclude that a decorator must be something which takes a function as an argument.

So the equating of functions differ in these two cae, namely equating with  function which takes another function as an argument, and equating two functions which don't take another function as argument.

How might this two differing in internal implementation?

Comment: If you are not passing a function as an argument (and returning a function) then it is not a decorator. I don't really understand your question, and I think you are confusing equating with assignment. `x = y` is an assignment, `x` and `y` now refer to the same object whatever its type might be, including function objects.  It is irrelevant what type of object `x` referred to before the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "equating functions" is really just a variable assignment. A function definition (with `def`) creates a function and assigns it to a variable name. After you do `func_1 = func_2`, you have 2 variables referring to the same function.

What happens in your decorator examples is a natural consequence of the previous paragraph. Leave a comment if you need further clarification on that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your question can be answered by explaining few terms.

1. You are using the term *"equating"* for what it is commonly called "assigning". `name = expr` is an assignment statement. The name `name` is given (assigned) to the object which is the result of the expression `expr`.
2. In Python functions are not treated special. This is sometimes expressed with the sentence *"functions are first class objects"* and basically it means that function objects can be assigned to variables (names), passed as arguments etc. the same way as numbers, strings and other objects.
3. A (function) decorator processes another function. It is a function that takes the function to be decorated as its argument and returns a "decorated" (i.e. enhanced or modifed in some way) version of it. Sometimes it only registers the function e.g. as a handler or as a part of an API and returns it unchanged. There is a special syntax for it:

```
@decorator
def func(...):
    pass
```

which is equivalent to:

```
func = decorator(func)
```

and also:

```
@decorator(args)
def func(...):
    pass
```

which is equivalent to:

```
_real_decorator = decorator(args)
func = _real_decorator(func)
```

Because this `@decorator` syntax is so simple to use and easy to read, you normally don't write:

```
func = decorator(func)
```

---

To summarize:

`func1 = some_func` is plain assignment, giving other name to `some_func`.

`func2 = create_function()` this would be called a function factory in some languages. You wrote that in your question.

`func = decorate_function(func)` this is a decoration of `func`

Note: there exist class decorators, they are very similar, but enhance class definitions instead of functions.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator looks like this:

```
def decorator_with_args(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(f: "the function being decorated"):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # inside here is the code that is actually executed
            # when calling the decorated function. This should
            # always include...
            f(*args, **kwargs)

            # and usually return its result
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

# or

def decorator_without_args(f: "the function being decorated"):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # as above
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

and is used by:

```
@decorator_with_args("some", "args")
def foo(x):
    print("foo:", x)  # or whatever

@decorator_without_args
def bar(x):
    print("bar:", x)
```

This is equivalent to defining each function without the `@decorator...` magic and applying the decorator afterwards

```
def baz(x):
    print("baz:", x)

baz = decorator_with_args("some", "arguments")(baz)
# or
baz = decorator_without_args(baz)
```

---

In your example code you call `foo` inside your decorator, then you decorate `foo` with that decorator, so you end up recursing infinitely. Every time you call `foo`, it runs your decorator code which also invokes `foo`. Every time your decorator invokes `foo`, it runs your decorator code which also invokes `foo`. Every time your decorator's decorator invokes `foo`, is runs your decorator code which also... etc